# Upgraded to fancybox version 2 and now fancybox doesn't fancy anymore

Tags: jquery, fancybox

If you look at this page http://ccc.allthingswebdesign.com/index.php/patterns/29 There is an image that if you click on it should open in a [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) window. In fact it used to until I upgraded to the newest version of fancybox and now it's broken. Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do to get it working again?

Comment: Your site is having Internal Server Error 500. Check with tools like Firebug / Chrome's Developer Tools.

Comment: I just tried my link and I'm not seeing the error.

Comment: You sure? See http://i.imgur.com/w5Ecq.png

Comment: I know the image isn't loading, that's a different issue i'm trying to sort out. The css file is old and I just need to take it out. Neither of those would cause this issue with fancybox.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your fancybox API options in your custom script? (v2.x option are new and not compatible with previous versions). Also, have you tried upgrading the fancybox CSS file too? (it seems like you are still using a v1.2.x fancybox css file)

Comment: I just updated the css file and i've also removed all of the fancybox options. Still does the same thing.

Comment: comments can be large so I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wonder if this script is making any noise to fancybox

```
$("a.img").hover( function () {
 if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) <= 8) {
  $(this).stop(false, true).toggleClass('imgHover');
 } else {
  $(this).stop(false, true).toggleClass('imgHover', 200);
 }
});
```

Could you disable it to verify that?

UPDATE:

I narrowed down your issue to these two scripts http://ccc.allthingswebdesign.com/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js and http://ccc.allthingswebdesign.com/assets/js/contactForm.js ... if you remove them, then fancybox works. My guess is that since the selector `#CommentForm` doesn't exist in that page, the validation script breaks the fancybox code. I guess you could apply a `php` filter to load those scripts in the contact page only.

Comment: I've commented it out. Still does nothing.

Comment: I narrowed down your issue to these two scripts http://ccc.allthingswebdesign.com/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js and http://ccc.allthingswebdesign.com/assets/js/contactForm.js ... if you remove them, then fancybox works. My guess is that since the selector `#CommentForm` doesn't exist in that page, the validation script breaks the fancybox code. I guess you could apply a `php` filter to load those scripts in the contact page only.

Comment: It seems that it's the jquery.validate.min.js script. I'll give it a shot like you said filtering based on whether my #CommentForm exists. How did you end up figuring out which script it was btw?

Comment: I removed all the scripts and fancybox worked. Then add them back and start removing from the most obvious, which normally are the other plugins  ;)